# Sharing session between two node apps using SSO

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, single-sign-on

I have an existing website which is built using express and node.js , I have to incorporate nodebb forum in that website which is again a different node application, I am using facebook login for both of them but I have to login into them seperately one by one(using same facebook app for both). What I want to do is,

1.Login via fb or any sso in the main site and the user should be logged in the forum via the same automatically.

2.How can I integrate nodebb in my website so that the look and feel doesn't change, it looks like I am on a completely different website, just need some tips to integrate nodebb in my existing website.

How can I achieve these two?

Answer (score 2):

(Hey there @Vipul, NodeBB dev here) When you establish the express session your app, what are you setting the cookie's `domain` to?

> ;domain=*domain* (e.g., '`example.com`', '`.example.com`' (includes all subdomains), '`subdomain.example.com`') If not specified, defaults to the host portion of the current document location.

-- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

You'll probably want to set it to `.your-domain.com`, and likewise for NodeBB (do it in the "Settings/Advanced" section):

[image: ... in NodeBB]

Then also make sure the `key` in your app is set to `express.sid`, which is the value we use, and that the secrets match.